# 2-3 divs - all have height of the tallest div - last div uses the rest of the space

Tags: html, css

I have two divs (if there is no thumbnail) or three divs (if there is a thumbnail) next to each other. They're called "Vote", "Thumbnail" and "Post". The "Vote" is always of the same height and width. The "Thumbnail" may exist or not exist. The "Thumbnail" sometimes is higher than the "Vote" or "Post" div, but other times the "Post" section is higher than the "Vote" and "Thumbnail" section because the post title takes up two or three lines.

**Here's an image that shows the possible variants and how I want it to behave (beware, mad paint skillz): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au4GD.png**

You see, it makes sure the two (three) heights match the biggest one. I've found a few solutions but these solutions do not work with the possibility of two/three section problem and the variable width of the last ("Post") section.

Is it even possible to solve this with HTML and CSS only?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse it's possible, could you make an attempt at it first? Then we'll try to help out.

Comment: Is this the kind of HTML/CSS you have so far? http://jsfiddle.net/u3vxgo6c/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `display: table-cell`?
http://jsfiddle.net/pqw9w97t/

Some time ago webdesingers had to use `<table>` fore entire page layout, because CSS positioning was broken. Now we can use pure CSS to make any elements behave like table cells without interfere content meaning - `<table>` is reserved for tabular data.

CSS has even more display mechanics yet to come: [Flexible Box Layout Working Drat](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)

Comment: Can you update this answer with the snippets from the fiddle?